# Replace HTML Comment along with string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In my project I have some html with comments surrounding text so I can find the text between particular comments and replace that text whilst leaving the comments so I can do it again.

I am having trouble getting the regex to work.

Here is an html line I am working on:

```
<td class="spaced" style="font-family: Garamond,Palatino,sans-serif;font-size: medium;padding-top: 10px;"><!--firstname-->Harrison<!--firstname--> <!--lastname-->Ford<!--lastname--> <span class="spacer"></span></td>
```

Now, here is the javascript/jquery that I have at the moment:

```
var thisval = $(this).val();  //gets replacement text from a text box
var thistoken = "firstname";

currentTemplate = $("#gentextCodeArea").text();  //fetch the text
var tokenstring = "<!--" + thistoken + "-->"
var pattern = new RegExp(tokenstring + '\\w+' + tokenstring,'i');
currentTemplate.replace(pattern, tokenstring + thisval + tokenstring);
$("#gentextCodeArea").text(currentTemplate);   //put the new text back
```

I think I'm pretty close, but I don't have the regex right yet.

The regex ought to replace the `firstname` with whatever is entered in the textbox for $thisval  (method is attached to keyup procedure on textbox).

Comment: Are you able to edit your HTML?

Comment: yes, I can do whatever I need - it is a template.  I couldn't think of a better way to do this.  I need the comments so I can display the html in my web page without showing the surrounding tokens AND still be able to replace the contents.

Comment: Then you should change your comments like`<!--firstname><!-->` to `<!--firstname-->`. That is a proper HTML comment

Comment: But Don't I need the `<!-->` to close the comment?  If I don't it will comment out everything that comes after it.

Comment: `-->` closes the comment

Comment: aaaaahhh - let me do that.  You know, I think I knew that at some point in the past...  thanks for that.

Comment: Also, you have `Harrison Ford` between the `firstname` comments. Shouldn't `Ford` be between the `lastname` comments?

Comment: Why not just wrap the names in `span` tags? It will make your code so much easier.

Comment: How are you using jQuery to find the input field?

Comment: When the user types in an edit box it fires a keyup event.  Actually, I think trincot is onto something... That might, indeed, be a better way.

Comment: It would be a better way. But you didn't ask for a better way.

Comment: No, I didn't, but I still don't have an answer for the way for which I sought.

Comment: @bgmCoder see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using plain `span` tags instead of comments would make things easier, but either way, I would suggest not using regular expressions for this. There can be border cases that may lead to undesired results.

If you stick with comment tags, I would iterate over the child nodes and then make the replacement, like so:

```js
$("#fname").on("input", function () {
    var thisval = $(this).val();  //gets replacement text from a text box
    var thistoken = "firstname";

    var between = false;
    $("#gentextCodeArea").contents().each(function () {
        if (this.nodeType === 8 && this.nodeValue.trim() === thistoken) {
            if (between) return false;
            between = true;
        } else if (between) {
            this.nodeValue = thisval;
            thisval = '';
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
New first name: <input id="fname">
<div id="gentextCodeArea">
    <!--firstname-->Harrison<!--firstname--> 
    <!--lastname-->Ford<!--lastname--> 
<span class="spacer"></span></div>
```

#### What went wrong in your code

- By using `text()` you don't get the comment tags. To get those, you need to use `html()` instead
- `replace()` does not mutate the variable given in the first argument, but *returns* the modified string. So you need to assign that back to `currentTemplate`
- It would be better to use `[^<]*` instead of `\w+` for matching the first name, as some first names have non-letters in them (hyphen, space, ...), and it may even be empty.

Here is the corrected version, but I insist that regular expressions are not the best solution for such a task:

```js
$("#fname").on("input", function () {
    var thisval = $(this).val();  //gets replacement text from a text box
    var thistoken = "firstname";

    currentTemplate = $("#gentextCodeArea").html();  //fetch the html
    var tokenstring = "<!--" + thistoken + "-->"
    var pattern = new RegExp(tokenstring + '[^<]*' + tokenstring,'i');
    currentTemplate = currentTemplate.replace(pattern, tokenstring + thisval + tokenstring);
    $("#gentextCodeArea").html(currentTemplate);   //put the new text back
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
New first name: <input id="fname">
<div id="gentextCodeArea">
    <!--firstname-->Harrison<!--firstname--> 
    <!--lastname-->Ford<!--lastname--> 
<span class="spacer"></span></div>
```

Comment: This is a much better way to go - and I'll use it, but I can't mark it as the answer the question I posted.  I still give you my vote.

Comment: I added a section to my answer that may interest you.

Comment: Yes, I will; I was just giving the other fellow a chance to update his answer since he was in the right direction.  But your answer is thoughtful and perfect; I hope you answer other questions I ask!

Answer (score 0):

here is a function which will generate an appropriate Regular expression:

```
function templatePattern(key) {
  return new RegExp(`<!--${key}-->(.*?)<!--${key}-->`);
}
```

the `(.*?)` means "match as little as possible," so it will stop at the first instance of the closing tag.
Example:

```
'<!--firstname-->Harrison<!--firstname--> <!--lastname-->Ford<!--lastname-->'
    .replace(templatePattern('firstname'), 'Bob')
    .replace(templatePattern('lastname'), 'Johnson')    // "Bob Johnson"
```

Comment: Where you have `key` - that is my problem, it needs to be a variable.  I mean, it needs to be the string variable.

Comment: @bgmCoder `${key}` gets interpolated to the value of `key`. This may look unfamiliar because it's an [ES2015 template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). The ES5 version would be `return new RegExp('<!--' + key + '-->(.*?)<!--' + key + '-->');`

Comment: Sure, but I don't need the key value - I need the name of the token inside the html comment.

Comment: the above method works for that as well, just match instead of replace. Usage: `'<!--firstname-->Harrison<!--firstname--> <!--lastname-->Ford<!--lastname-->'.match(templatePattern('firstname'))[1]` which evaluates to `Harrison`

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function(){
  function onKeyUp(event)
  {
    if(event.which === 38)  // if key press was the up key
    {
      $('.firstname_placeholder').text($(this).val());
    }
  }
  
  $('#firstname_input').keyup(onKeyUp);
});
```

```css
input[type=text]{width:200px}
```

```html
<input id='firstname_input' type='text' placeholder='type in a name then press the up key'/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td ><span class='firstname_placeholder'>Harrison</span> <span class='lastname_placeholder'>Ford</span> <span class="spacer"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This isn't really a solution to the regex problem; but the downvote isn't mine.